# How to use .map() method for looping Two different array from API?

Tags: javascript, api, methods

I have the API has 2 different Array, I would like to display on html both Arrays.`const displayProducts = (data) => {
const dataArray = [data.Products, data.Prices];

```
const htmlString = dataArray[(0, 1)]
  .map((item) => {
    return `<div class="products">
      <h2>${item.ProductType}<span class="span-available">.${item.ProductDescription}</span></h2>
      <div class="products-right-wrapper">
        <div class="products-price-wrapper">
          <div class="products-price-container">
              <sub class="discount-price">$17.99</sub>
              <p>${item.Price}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>`;
  })
  .join('');

productList.innerHTML = htmlString;`
```

Comment: Clear to be on this question. I have two different API Object i have to map thru both and using dotnotation to access that element.

Comment: I tried something like this `dataArray[0].map((product) => { dataArray[1].map((price) => {` but could not figure that out how can i return only one.

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't super clear, but I think you are looking for [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap).

```js
const htmlString = dataArray.flatMap(data => data.map((item) => ...)
)
```

Comment: I have one API has two Array (Products, Prices), When i map the products i am accessing the object like Products.map((product) => { return `<p>${product.Type}</p>` }).join('');  But at the same return i cannot access Prices Object. I was thinking i have to map Prices as well. Thank you for help